# what is the noise remaining after median filtering?

Tags: python, image-processing, filter

So I'm apply the median filter to an image, but at the output, there's blue semi-dots appearing. What are they?

This is the output

[image]

And the python code for anyone interested

```
from scipy.ndimage.filters import median_filter
from matplotlib.pylab import imread, imshow, subplot, title, show, get_cmap

img = imread('images/speckle.gif')
new = median_filter(img, 3)

subplot(121); imshow(img, cmap=get_cmap('gray'));
title('The original')
subplot(122); imshow(new, cmap=get_cmap('gray'));
title('Filtered with the median_filter')

show()
```

EDIT:

I've fixed. It turns out that the image was not pure gray-scale after all.
I don't know how that's possible. I've changed the imread function from pyplot to skimage.io

```
from skimage import io
img = io.imread('images/speckle.gif', as_grey=True)
```

The rest of the code is the same.
This is my new output.

[image]

The strange thing is, how come the pyplot does not have any options for converting an rgb image to gray-scale?!?!

Comment: That looks a lot like matlab's UI functions.

Comment: what does? This is pure python code.

Comment: If the original image was pure gray-scale, the result should be also. If there's even a minor deviation, all bets are off.

Comment: So the original was not pure gray-scale? But it looks so ... gray. Here's the link of the original picture. Just in case anyone would like to check if its pure gray-scale or not

Comment: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/images/fce5noi3.gif

Comment: I just ran a script to check all the pixel values. Every single one is perfectly gray, as in red equals green equals blue. No idea what the problem is.

Comment: Have you tried saving the filtered image and viewing it with something other than matplotlib?

Comment: Yes and  got the same outcome

Comment: I ran ImageMagick's median filter over your original and it does not produce blue dots, so I deduce that your median filter is implemented incorrectly. As the image is a GIF, I would try flattening it on top of a solid black image before filtering it to avoid transparent pixel effects. Failing that, I would try reducing the contrast before filtering (to prevent overflows when filtering) or using a 5x5 median to see if that is better or worse.

Comment: I've fixed. The problem was it was not pure gray-scale

Comment: I've also verified that the original is pure gray. I think your solution just masks the problem by using a format that contains only one value per pixel rather than three.